# Can not run docker command on windows 7

Tags: docker

can not run docker on windows7 command after installation, and there is nothing in virtualbox.

I have tried uninstall and install other versions, run install application administrately and try another dirver but above does not work.

...

when installation finished, i clicked the docker quickstart terminal, and it show me this error message:

```sh
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:53822: connectex: No connection could be made because the tar
get machine actively refused it.
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´...
Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a reminder, there are sort of 3 ways to use docker on Windows, if one doesn't work you may want to try another one:

- use docker [Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/): it requires windows 10 Pro (In fact Hyper-V maybe it's an option for you)
- use docker [Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/): the one you may have installed on windows 7, it uses Virtualbox and a docker machine VM.
- use Virtualbox directly: install a linux distribution with shared folder only for your docker usage

Now since you are on option 2, you should have a virtualbox installed, so you can check if the underlying docker machine is launched by launching virtualbox, it should list the installed vm.

If the vm is not started: you will have to search the problem on virtualbox side, error logs or popup: trying to launch the vm manually directly from virtualbox application will help you

If the vm is started: there may be a connection problem between your host (windows) and your vm (boot2docker), you could try to connect to the vm via bash using "boot2docker ssh" as it is indicated in the quick start. If it works, the connection problem could come from a firewall.

Check if the [quick start](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) happened correctly when you have luanched it.

I don't want to make proselitism on other solution, but it may be simpler to use a linux directly in virtualbox (option 3), at least at the beginning to get more familar with docker. 
The other simpler option would be to use windows 10

I'm sorry it's not a complete solution, but indications, and it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks very mush for your suggestions.I have given up to install docker daemon on windows 7, and i have chosen to connect to a remote docker daemon.There is not a vm in virtualbox, and when i try to run a command to create it appeared the error again.It shows that the target machine actively refuse it, i do not know why.

Comment: @pythonist Happy to see you have your solution, you may check to create manually a vm in virtualbox using an ISO for installation, or a prebuilt vdi image, see here https://www.osboxes.org/virtualbox-images/. If it doesn't work try to reinstall the last virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

docker server is not running properly. check is you can run `docker ps` or  `docker version` command successfully.

Comment: ```shell
C:\>docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.7
 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a
 Built:             Wed Jul 31 15:18:18 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the de
fault daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.```

Comment: no matter what docker command i try to run, it will show me such error. I closed firewall and other safety software.

Comment: yeah demon is not running. try installing docker toolbox with administrator

Comment: Try the "Docker Quickstart terminal" Application